# Enviar email con Nodemailer en Locallhost (ReferenceError: require is not defined)

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

Quiero enviar los datos de este formulario con Nodemailer. Pero cuando le doy click al botón `enviar` en el navegador (locallhost) en la consola me sale el siguiente error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Mi versión de node es `v7.9.0`.

Debo aclarar que cuando ejecuto app.js desde el terminal (sin la función) `function enviar(){}` si envía el correo.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo4</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Formulario</h1>
        <select>
            <option>Vida</option>
            <option>Hogar</option>
            <option>Auto</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="email" value="email">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="enviar()">
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
function enviar(){

    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '****@gmail.com',
            pass: '******'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"****" <****@gmail.com>',
        to: '****@***.com',
        subject: 'Lorem ipsum',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum',
        html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });
    
};
```

**app.js** sin la función `function enviar(){}` Probado desde el terminal si envía el correo.

```js
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '****@gmail.com',
            pass: '******'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"****" <****@gmail.com>',
        to: '****@***.com',
        subject: 'Lorem ipsum',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum',
        html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el require antes de declarar la función, sino tratara de resolver "require" dentro del scope de la función en lugar del scope de la aplicación

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

function enviar(){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede realizar una acción del lado del cliente como esta, para ello debería crear un servidor con nodejs (por ejemplo), y por medio de sockets o http realizar el llamado de la misma.